# How to unlink two images from two different folders at once in php

Tags: php

I have this code which is supposed to delete two image files from two diffrent folders at the same time. The issue is, only one image is deleted. the other is not. I have tried different methods but still the same issue.

Below is my code.

```
<?php
$colname_albumedit = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['arf'])) {
    $colname_albumedit = $_GET['arf'];
}

$query_album = "SELECT * FROM galbum WHERE alID = '" . $colname_albumedit . "'";
$result_album = mysqli_query($connKcla, $query_album);
$row_album = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_album);
$totalRows_album = mysqli_num_rows($result_album);

$query_album_images = "SELECT * FROM gimage WHERE alID = '" . $colname_albumedit . "'";
$result_album_images = mysqli_query($connKcla, $query_album_images);
$row_album_images = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_album_images);
$totalRows_album_images = mysqli_num_rows($result_album_images);


if ((isset($_POST["form_del"])) && ($_POST["form_del"] == "adalbumdel")) {

    $target = "../gallery/albums/";
    $targett = "../gallery/images/";

    $imID = $_GET['arf'];
    $sql_query = "SELECT alImage FROM galbum WHERE alID = $imID";
    $photoresult = mysqli_query($connKcla, $sql_query);
    $row_album = mysqli_fetch_assoc($photoresult);

    if (($row_album['alImage']) != 0) {
        unlink($target . $row_album['alImage']);
    }

    $sql_queryy = "SELECT albumRef FROM gimage WHERE albumRef = $imID";
    $photoresultt = mysqli_query($connKcla, $sql_queryy);
    $row_album_images = mysqli_fetch_assoc($photoresultt);

    if (($row_album_images['albumRef']) != 0) {
        unlink($targett . $row_album_images['albumRef']);
    }

    $query_del = "DELETE FROM galbum WHERE alID = $colname_albumedit";
    $result_del = mysqli_query($connKcla, $query_del);

    $queryy_del = "DELETE FROM gimage WHERE alID = $colname_albumedit";
    $resultt_del = mysqli_query($connKcla, $queryy_del);

    if ($result_del && $resultt_del) {
        $updateGoTo = "confirm.php";
        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
            $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
            $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
        header("Location: " . $updateGoTo);
    } else {
        header("Location: error.php");
    }
}
```

The table gImage looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gimage ( 
    imID bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    imImage varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    albumRef bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (imID), KEY alID (albumRef) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Comment: This line $sql_queryy  = "SELECT albumRef FROM gimage WHERE albumRef = $imID"; looks weird. Why select albumRef when you already have it via $imID. Think here you are making a mistake.

Comment: @Kordi: There are two separate tables and when inputting data, the id of the data entered in the album table is stored in the images table with the image name. It is supposed to help when querying to select all records from the images table where the requested id matches the id in the albumRef field

Comment: but look at the query you select what you already have. Could you post the structure of your table in the question. And then you try to unlink the unlink($targett . $row_album_images['albumRef']); -- why not unlink($targett . $imID);

Comment: @Kordi: I have tried that but it still did not work. only the album unlink is working.

Comment: That don't work, cause its the semantical the same. How does your tables look like!

Comment: This is the image table:Table structure for table `gimage`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gimage` (
  `imID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imImage` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `albumRef` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imID`),
  KEY `alID` (`albumRef`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think, just replace this code

```
$sql_queryy = "SELECT albumRef FROM gimage WHERE albumRef = $imID";
$photoresultt = mysqli_query($connKcla, $sql_queryy);
$row_album_images = mysqli_fetch_assoc($photoresultt);

if (($row_album_images['albumRef']) != 0) {
    unlink($targett . $row_album_images['albumRef']);
}
```

with this code.

```
$sql_queryy = "SELECT imImage FROM gimage WHERE albumRef = $imID";
$photoresultt = mysqli_query($connKcla, $sql_queryy);
$row_album_images = mysqli_fetch_all($photoresultt);
foreach ($row_album_images as $row) {
    unlink($targett . $row[0]);
}
```

**Recommendation**

Rename your variable $imID cause it is in reality the albumId. As you can see in your code in the lines

```
$imID = $_GET['arf'];
$sql_query = "SELECT alImage FROM galbum WHERE alID = $imID";
```

Comment: Thnaks. But that wont work. Cause it would search for the image Id of the record in the image table that matches the id stored in the $imID variable. Say the id in the $imID is 2. it means, it will search for the record in the image table where the id is the same as the $imID.

Comment: What i am trying to do is to unlink all records from the images folder where the albumRef is equal to the $imID form the Get

Comment: I know this but your code at this point makes no sense. Think the image file name is saved in imImage not in albumRef or? Ok now i understand perhaps the problem. How does the table galbum looks like? And the problem is with deleteting the 2nd image or?

Comment: Yes. The image file name is imImage. Say if my album Id is 2 and a number of images in the the image table have 2 stored in their albumRef field. Now its to delete all those records with the albumRef field as 2 and also unlink their corresponding files whose names are stored in the imImage field.

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael Now i understand it, I update my answer. So $imID is in reality the albumId. Query this and then delete all Images in a foreach loop. If you follow my recommendation you have to rename the $imID in your whole code, in my solution, too.

Comment: Thanks @Kordi. I just got it working now. I just replaced the WHERE imID = $imID with WHERE albumRef = $imID and it unlinks from both folders now. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael You are welcome. But if you have more than one image you need my solution for delete all Images. So my solution works for one or more images. And please credit me with an upvote and helpful answers. Thanks

Comment: Yes. will update it to your code. Thanks again. Will definately credit you now.

Comment: Hello @Kordi Please i am trying to use this code with mysqli_fetch_all on a server without msqlnd installed. So i get an error message. i now try a while loop. The image name gets deleted from the db, but the images remain in the folder.

Comment: This is the code $sql_queryy = "SELECT imImage FROM gimage WHERE imID = '$chkbxk'";
   $photoresultt = mysqli_query($connBiscup, $sql_queryy);
   $row_album_images = mysqli_fetch_assoc($photoresultt);
   
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($photoresultt)) { 

    unlink($target . $row[0]);
    unlink($targett . $row[0]);
   }